# Use else in dict comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

From two dictionaries:

```
d1 = {a:a for a in 'abcdefg'}
d2 = {n:n for n in range(10)}
```

How can I create a third one like:

```
new_dict = {k:d1[k] if k in d1.keys() else k:d2[k]  for k in 'abc123' }
```

It's throwing a syntax Error, but with list comprehension seems to be fine:

```
[a if a else 2 for a in [0,1,0,3]]
out[]: [2, 1, 2, 3]
```

Moreover, why this works:

```
{k:d1[k]  for k in 'abc123' if k in d1.keys() }
```

and this doesn't:

```
{k:d1[k] if k in d1.keys() for k in 'abc123' }
```

Comment: What is an expected output for `new_dict`? Is fairly unclear what you asking for. You are currently using ternary operator for pairs `k:v` which is illegal, but you easily may use it for `k` and for `v` individually.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski I want to create a new dict with the keys 'abc123' , the values for those keys are in the two other dicts I already have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use the *key-value* pair in the `else` part of ternary conditional like so.

Do this instead:

```
new_dict = {k: d1[k] if k in d1 else d2[int(k)]  for k in 'abc123'}
#                                    ^^<- make value d2[int(k)] on else
print(new_dict)
#{'2': 2, '1': 1, 'b': 'b', 'a': 'a', 'c': 'c', '3': 3}
```

Note that `if k in d1` checks if `k` is a key in the dictionary `d1`. No need to call the `keys` method.

Answer (score 3):

As described, it seems like both your `d1` and `d2` are artifacts of how you envision solving the problem and aren't essential.  How about simply:

```
>>> dictionary = {k: int(k) if k.isdigit() else k for k in 'abc123'}
>>> dictionary
{'b': 'b', '3': 3, '2': 2, '1': 1, 'a': 'a', 'c': 'c'}
>>>
```

Or is there more to the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, actually the keys are words from a list, I don't have an easy way like the method .isdigit() to distinguish those. But they map either on d1 or d2.

Answer (score 3):

```
{k:v1 if condition1 else v2 for k in some_list}
```

Which is equal to:

```
{k:(v1 if condition1 else v2) for k in some_list}
```

The latter is more easily understood

Answer (score 2):

This is a general answer for dictionary comprehension with "else". I came across this post when I google-searched it, so I hope it helps future googlers.

So lets say I want to create dictionary with a condition on both k and v

A naive way to solve this would look something like this:

```
{k:v if (condition) else otherk:otherv for k,v in some_dictionary}
```

This doesn't work, as mentioned before by Moses Koledoye.

However, you can use the following for each part:

```
{k if condition1 else otherK: v if condition2 else otherV for k,v in some_dictionary}
```

Note that here, we conditional the key's assignment and the value's assignment.
The most important thing to pay attention to here is the location of the : delimeter between the keys and the values. Hope this helps.

The following is an example for getting a custom dictionary in the following from:
for the english alphabet
from letters A-G would show a positive value for the order of the upper-case letters
from letters J-Z shows a negative value for the order of the small-case letters

This is an example for different keys and values based on a certain condition.
I hope this is explained well enough.

```
>>> def less_than_H_ascii_val(x):
...     return x < ord('H')-ord('A')
...
>>> {chr(k+ord('A')) if less_than_H_ascii_val(k) else chr(k+ord('a')):
... k if less_than_H_ascii_val(k) else -k 
... for k in range(26)}
{'A': 0, 'C': 2, 'B': 1, 'E': 4, 'D': 3, 'G': 6, 'F': 5, 'i': -8, 'h': -7, 'k': -10, 'j': -9, 'm': -12, 'l': -11, 'o': -14, 'n': -13, 'q': -16, 'p': -15, 's': -18, 'r': -17, 'u': -20, 't': -19, 'w': -22, 'v': -21, 'y': -24, 'x': -23, 'z': -25}
```